# Automatically load clojure libraries on cider connection

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I constantly find myself doing multiple manual `(require '[my.lib :as foo])` right after I start cider with `M-x cider-jack-in` in my clojure projects. I suspect there must be a hook to run some code on a successful connection. Is there? The alternative would be to put all requires in an external file and just `(use 'that.namespace)` but lazy as I am, I want to even skip that step if possible.

UPDATE:

Putting the forms in .lein/profiles.clj :injections is fine as long as one uses them exclusively in the Repl (as per `lein repl`). To make them available from the nrepl in emacs one must use the second solution named by arrdem below.

Here is some [more comprehensive info](http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2013/06/04/clojure-workflow-reloaded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leiningen's `:injections` [feature](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L156) is the cannonical way to pull this one off. Once Lein boots a Clojure instance, the code in `:injections` gets evaluated allowing you as you say to populate the `user` namespace with libraries that you use all the time.

Another approach is to (ab)use the file `user.clj` by adding a `:dev` profile with a dev-only source path that "happens" to contain a `user.clj` with preloading code in it. This is done in [Grimoire](http://github.com/clojure-grimoire/grimoire) with the file `dev/user.clj` which serves to create some utility functions in the REPL.